# Requisição ajax para servidor laravel

Tags: ajax, api, laravel-5, restful

Meu minimundo é o seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um API para uma padaria, onde a mesma poderá esta no mesmo servidor ou servidor diferente, estou utilizando o framework `laravel` na versão `5.2.*`. Com intuito de facilitar o trabalho fiz alguns controllers apenas no `painel administrativo` por exemplo de produtos. Em meus controllers eu verifico se está vindo uma requisição json. Desta forma sei se é uma requisição ou se é um view que devo retornar, programei da seguinte maneira:

```
 public function index(){
    $produtos =  Produto::all();

    if(Request::wantsJson()){
        return $produtos;
    }else{
        return view('Produto.listProduto', compact('produtos'));
    }
}
```

Dito isto e feito todo processo e o mesmo sido testado, estou tentando consumir estes dados de um outro website, que no caso seria o site principal. A minha ideia é listar todos produtos e retorna-los para um JSON.

No html utilizo o JQUERY para fazer esta requisição desta maneira:

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/produtos', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Em minha rota no `painel administrativo` programei da seguinte maneira:

```
Route::singularResourceParameters();
Route::resource('produtos', 'ProdutoController');
```

Com tudo esta dando um erro no `console` do meu `browser`, utilizo o `google chrome` porém testei em outros e deu o mesmo tipo de problema.

A saída foi

> Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em http://localhost:8000/produtos. (Motivo: o cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' não está presente).

O que posso esta fazendo de errado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que ser instalado via `composer.phar` um pacote para liberação do `CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`, o [***barryvdh/laravel-cors (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)***](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Na linha de *comando* **digite**:

> `php composer require "barryvdh/laravel-cors"`

no arquivo `config/app.php` em `providers` acrescente:

```
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

depois de instalado digite mais essa linha de comando:

> `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"`

que vai copiar o arquivo de configuração para a ***pasta*** `config` com o nome de `cors.php`.

Por fim nas **rotas** (`route`) coloque um `middleware` igual exemplo abaixo:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(Router $router){
    $router->get('api', 'ApiController@index');
});
```

Se quiser fazer uma configuração melhorada faça no arquivo `config/cors.php`, o seu padrão é:

```
<?php
return [
    /*
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     | Laravel CORS
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
     | allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders and allowedMethods can be set to array('*')
     | to accept any value.
     |
     */
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],
];
```

***Links:***

- [barryvdh/laravel-cors - Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://packagist.org/packages/barryvdh/laravel-cors)
- [Laravel-5 REST API and CORS](https://blog.nikhilben.com/2015/09/02/laravel5-rest-api-and-cors/)
- [Laravel 5.1 - easily enable CORS](http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/)

Comment: como faria isto ;

Comment: Fiz uma edição.

Comment: Could not open input file: composer.phar soltou este erro no log

Comment: dei o composer require e funcionou

Comment: fiz um breve resumo e sequencia de comandos @RenanRodrigues !

Comment: Faz so a alteração do .phar porque aqui no meu nao funcionou desta maneira, da outra deu certinho

Comment: Qual é o seu sistema?

Comment: meu sistema é windows 10

Comment: deveria funcionar mas, tudo bem!

Comment: na verdade é o nome do documento, é composer.json não composer.phar

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkk eu imagina que era algo de errado ai mesmo! porque eu uso assim porque uso windows 10, mas, sem problemas instale esse passo a passo ele vai liberar para você! tem configurações vou colocar na resposta!